# VBA Filtering - Getting Error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filter a Data Table with VBA but I didn't manage to

If I write the Following ... It filters perfectly.

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("OPT").Range.AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1 _
    :="=QQQ", Operator:=xlAnd
```

Now if in the Cell `C2` I enter the value `QQQ`

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("OPT").Range.AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1 _
       :="=" & Range("C2"), Operator:=xlAnd
```

Excel filters and gives no results...  I tried using `Range("C2").Value` and `Range("C2").Text` but have same issue... no result in the filtering ... Does anyone have an idea of where my syntax is wrong... Thanks

Comment: It has to be range.value in any case. Is ListObjects("OPT") a data table? Try applying the filter to a single cell and replace Range("C2") by ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Value.

Comment: yes `ListObjects("OPT") ` is a table linked to a Powerpivot Data Model... I tried `ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Value` but didnt work as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this out on Excel 2010, and you can simply reference the Range of the value to use and it will filter. So for your example `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("OPT").Range.AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=Range("C2"), Operator:=xlAnd` will work and filter the list.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that there isn't a value in C2 or the value is not in the 17th row of the table. Even you code `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("OPT").Range.AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1 _
       :="=" & Range("C2"), Operator:=xlAnd` works for me

Comment: I solved it as you did it.... with code on a single line...  but when code is on 2 lines like in my question not working.... Pretty weird... dt know why